# nested object disappears after function call

Tags: javascript, object

I've been trying to add an object inside an object, but this one disappears after I call a function:

I have one object 'item'

```
  const item = {
    id,
    type: 'instance',
    parent_id: null,
  }
```

I then call an API to get an other object of datas.

```
try {
 const res = await api.getData()
 console.log(res.data) // return { key1: value1, key2: value2 }
} catch(error) {
 console.log(error)
}
```

I add those key/value pair to an 'instance_setting' object inside item.

```
item.instance_setting = res.data

console.log(item) // return { id: 'xxx', type: 'instance', 'parent_id': 'xxx', instance_setting: {key1: value1, key2: value2 }}
```

So far all is doing fine.

Then I call a function 'MUTATE_DATA' to add this object into my state, which trigger the unexpected behavior. Here is the whole code:

```
const MUTATE_DATA = (item) => {
  state.menuItems.push(item)
  state.newItems.push({ id: item.id })
}

const useAddInstance = async (id) => {

  const item = {
    id,
    type: 'instance',
    parent_id: null,
  }

 try {
 const res = await api.getData()
 item.instance_setting = res.data

 MUTATE_DATA(item)
 console.log(item) // return { id: 'xxx', type: 'instance', 'parent_id': 'xxx'}

} catch(error) {
 console.log(error)
}
```

You can see in the console.log(item) my object instance_setting disappeared.

I know the line making problem is

```
state.newItems.push({ id: item.id })
```

but I do not understand why this would make this nested object disappear.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've simplified the code a lot to be easily readable and go streight to the point. If I comment the line state.newItems.push({ id: item.id }) the console.log(item) returns the right info. So there must be something here in how i push an 'id' object into which I assign item.id I don't think the api logic is important here but I could be wrong. mplingjan thanks for the typo correction...

Comment: "*I know the line making problem is `state.newItems.push({ id: item.id })`*" - I very much doubt that. I'm pretty certain that the line related to the problem is `state.menuItems.push(item)`, and somewhere else in your application is code that accesses the `menuItems` array and `delete`s the property. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Bergi, that's a very good point, I'll dig into that, indeed I've got a computed property somewhere doing some stuff to that array.

Answer (score -1):

As Bergi stated, a computed property somewhere else in the code was deleting the instance_setting into state.newItems